# xfce4 pulseaudio plugin - glib update..? Don't know what I'm doing

Tags: pulseaudio, xfce

Need to start by saying I'm a total noob at linux.
I've started learning over the past week and messing around with Crouton - installed trusty xfce.
I'm trying to do something simple - install the pulseaudio plugin panel:
https://bluesabre.org/2018/04/21/xfce-pulseaudio-plugin-0-4-0-and-0-4-1-released/

Theres an incredible lack of documentation on where what and how. Some people say its in xfce goodies, but I can't locate it. I just downloaded the above version and read up on how to extract and configure. 
After running configure, I was missing several things, which I managed to install with apt-get:
intltool
X window system libraries (googled what to install, xserver-xorg-dev)
libpulse-mainloop-glib

Now I have no clue what any of this or what I'm even installing, just wildly guessing, but not I've hit a wall with :
* The required package glib-2.0 was found on your system,
*** but the installed version (2.40.2) is too old.

No idea what to do or if any of this is even along the right lines, just to install a simple panel app...

Hope someone can lend a hand here, thanks